# jQuery Autocomplete Solr multiple fields

Tags: jquery, solr, autocomplete

i am currently trying to implement jquery autocomplete for a Solr index. Inside this solr index I have multiple fields the autocomplete should take care of. To keep it simple, I am currently just working with two fields:

- ac_event_title
- ac_event_information

As long as I only wanna search for one field, it works without any problems, but I dont know how to implement this with two or more fields, this is what my code actually looks like:

```
$search_el.autocomplete({
      source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url : 'http://192.168.82.75:8983/solr/local/select',
          dataType : 'jsonp',
          jsonp : 'json.wrf',
          data: {
            q: 'ac_event_title:'+$search_el.val()+' OR ac_event_information:'+$search_el.val(),
            wt: 'json',
            fq: 'ss_type:event',
            hl: 'true',
            'hl.fl': 'ac_event_title,ac_event_information'
          },
          success : function(data) {
            var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
            response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
              return {
                label : value.ac_event_title[0]
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength : 1
    });
```

So the problem in general is that I dont know how to tell the autocomplete, "if the result is in field "ac_event_title" show "ac_event_title" and if the result is in field "ac_event_information" show "ac_event_information".

Comment: No matter where， you can show all filed， because solr is not tell you which filed is hit  。

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Solr 5.0** and above then you need not to define the separate dictionary for multiple fields. You can copy the required fields to a new `suggest_field` using `copyField` and then create the dictionary for `suggest_field`. The suggester fields should be stored in the solr, so `stored=true` will be required in the field definition.

otherwise you can use the below configuration for your old solr versions.

---

You can configure multiple suggestion dictionary in solr `suggestComponent` and then add the dictionary into the `requestHandler`.  You can add the other parameter as per your requirement. This configuration is put into `solrconfig.xml`.

Check the below configuration for example:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">suggest_field</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>

    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">suggest1</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">state</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>


<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest1</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
    <str name="suggest.collate">false</str>
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```